# How to visually conceptualize this Javascript recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to visually understand what happens when this recursive code is run. I don't understand how the end result is 9.
In my mind, the `f(x - 1)` will iterate until it returns 5, then you add 1 which equals 6.

```
let f = x => {
  if (x === 0) {
    return 5
  }
  return 1 + f(x - 1)
}
let y = f(4)
console.log(y)
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you show the steps of how the code will run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the reasoning backwards. It isn't that one gets added once at the very end, one gets added after each resursive call returns. Think about this line:

```
return 1 + f(x - 1)
```

Once the recursive `f` call returns, one is added to that result. Then this recursive call returns, and one is added again. That keeps happening until the initial call returns.

Since one is added once per recursive call, and it will recurse four times, and the base case returns 5, this function ends up basically just calculating

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 5 == 9
```

Comment: The return result of ```f()``` is 1 and a function call, which then returns 1 and a function call until only 5 is returned.

Comment: @Zein.Mrwan Yes, essentially. Nina's answer might help solidify the understanding. When you're trying to understand the operation of a recursive function, it's often helpful to print some data out while it's running.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a level for an indention of a log and look which level has an input and return value.

```js
function f(x, level = 0) {
    console.log(level, '>>'.repeat(level + 1), x);
    var v = x === 0
        ? 5
        : 1 + f(x - 1, level + 1);
    console.log(level, '<<'.repeat(level + 1), v);
    return v;
}

console.log('result', f(4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```